# In a Derby DBMS, How can I pad a number with zeros?

Tags: sql, derby

```
VALUES TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR( { fn  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH,  -6  ,  
        CURRENT_DATE) }) AS CHAR(4) ) AS VARCHAR(4)))  || '-' ||     
        TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH( { fn  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -6  ,   
          CURRENT_DATE) }) AS CHAR(2) ) AS VARCHAR(2)))
```

The above statement returns 5 instead of 05 for MONTH(xxx)
which is not desired. It is not correct for comparisons
as 11 is smaller than 5 where in essense 11 is actually bigger
than 5

Edit:
With the JavaDB/Derby SQL statement above, I'd like to get
for example today is 2013-11-23, six months before was 2013-05-23
When comparing

```
select p.ProductCode , p.ProductName as pn, sum( od.NetSales) AS Sales      
 from   
  products p   

  INNER JOIN order_details od ON (p.ProductCode = od.ProductCode)  
  INNER JOIN orders o ON (od.OrderCode = o.OrderCode)   
  where   TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR(o.PurchaseDateTime) AS CHAR(4)) AS VARCHAR(4))) || '-' ||    
  TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH(o.PurchaseDateTime)  AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2)))      
              >

  TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR( { fn  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH,  -6   ,   CURRENT_DATE) }) AS CHAR(4) ) AS VARCHAR(4)))  || '-' ||    
  TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH( { fn  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -6  ,   CURRENT_DATE) }) AS CHAR(2) ) AS VARCHAR(2)))         

       group by p.ProductCode, p.PRODUCTNAME
```

orders that are within the range are not included.
Whereas I want to include them
Hope you understand

Thanks
Jack

Comment: Difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you remove everything that is not directly connected to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to format my data in my application. Use SQL to select the data that you want; use JDBC to fetch that data into variables in your program (e.g., use ResultSet.getDate() to get the value of a date column); use the Java libraries to format the data as you desire (e.g., use SimpleDateFormat to format your date data).

To learn how to use the ResultSet methods such as getDate: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(int)

To learn how to use SimpleDateFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html